# Using javascript within JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am writing a html login form which gets the user Id as input and confirm button for the user to confirm.. After the user enters the user ID I want to set that value in a session variable and retrieve in the next page which JSP.

```
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE=JavaScript>
  {
  funtion confirm()
  {

  String id = document.login.name.value;
    HttpSession s= request.getSession(true);
    s.setAttribute("user",id);
    document.login.action = document.location.protocol + "//" + "test.com" + "/jsp/confirm/con.jsp";
    }
  }
```

In the next page which is a JSP file, I get the session value using below scriptlets

```
<% session.getAttribute("user"):%>
```

When I click on confirm button, it does nothing and the IE debugger throws

**confirm();**

**The value of the property 'confirm' is null or undefined, not a Function object**

Could you please help me with this as I am not clear why it does not work.

Comment: Are you disallowed from using a proper javascript <script> tag within your code? That shall be a more maintainable approach.

Comment: Alright! I used the script tag but the result is same :(

Comment: Should be `function` instead of `funtion`, but mixing Java in your Javascript is not gonna fly.

Comment: Any other opinions from experts? My question is very specific and I am already aware of the conceptual part which is explained in the link that is used to mark my post as duplicate :|